# Python in Windows

Tags: python

I am new to Python and need some help.

i need to write a script that will look for file in c:\script\test\ directory with ext ".dat" and find "^" in there and replace with "|"

i am not sure how to write this. There will only be one file for a day in the directory with the current date as the file name.

Please help. I am not a good programmer obviously

thanks

Comment: Do you **really** want to learn or its just this one script you care about?

Comment: When you say "in there" do you mean the filename or inside the file? These are two incredibly different things.

Comment: Wayne, it is in the file

Gollum , i am not being rude, but this is the only one that i need to handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\script\test\*.dat"):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(data.replace("^", "|"))
```

should work in Python 2.6 and 2.7. Make sure you make a backup of your file first.

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://diveintopython3.ep.io/table-of-contents.html

You'll be interested in `endswith`, `open`, and `replace`.  `splitext` could be good if you're extra-careful.

Answer (score 0):

### Example: Check if file exists or not?

```
import os.path
# os.path - The key to File I/O
os.path.exists("foo.txt")
```

To learn more details : [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

### Resources to learn more:

Use this excellent resource if you want to learn the basics in organized way :[Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) - should clear your doubts about how to do string operations.

@Chris's answer has a very good link in it, so use that one to learn more.

*note: Anyone here can give you exact code but you won't learn that way.*